# Magento 2.4.1 Developer Mode not working

Tags: magento2.2.4, developer-mode, docker, magento2.4.1

i have installed Magento 2.4.1 via Docker and tried to change to developer mode. The problem is, that the developer option dont show up in the settings. I have tried:

1. Setting Developer Mode in nginx conf
2. Setting Developer Mode in .htaccess
3. Setting Developer Mode in the env.php
4. Change it in the console with bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer the result:
   Enabled developer mode.

Any ideas why it does not work?

Thank you all

Comment: I've seen docker images where it's set in the container. Where is your image,  docker file or compose file?

Comment: It is Compose File

Comment: Ok it was one Environment Variable of the PHP Docker. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there was a Docker with a environment variable. I changed it and now it is working. Thanks to @Dominic Xigen

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have `pub/static/.htaccess`? Magento uses this file to generate the symlinks in the `pub/static` folder.

If not add this [.htaccess](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/pub/static/.htaccess) file to the `pub/static` folder.

Comment: No there is no pub/static.htaccess file